# Koala does not see .sass files

Tags: sass, koala

I`m trying to figure out how Koala works with SCSS or SASS style files. But, when I open my project in Koala, it see .js or .css files, but none with the .sass or .scss extension. Have someone any ideas, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Koala can't see the _boostrap.scss file because of the underscore. Try renaming the file "_bootstrap.scss" to "bootstrap.scss".

Comment: Thanks  @HonzaZidek for your comment. Thanks for your edits ZevSpitz .